# Fixing a corrupted Windows Server 2003 server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, ntfs

I have a Windows Server 2003 server that is being mainly used for some reporting done in SQL Server.

Recently Windows has started complaining about being corrupted, we are getting an NTFS error 55:

```
The file system structure on the disk is corrupt and unusable. Please run the chkdsk utility on the volume \Device\HarddiskVolume1.
```

The server is RAID 5 and I did have a disk die however the RAID never went degraded since I have a hotspare. I replaced the hot spare and I'm still having problems.

When I run chkdsk I get tons of messages.. some are:

```
Deleting corrupted attribute record (128, "") from file record segment 194746
```

Those go on for a while. Then it deletes some orphan files. Then it does

```
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 132426
```

And that goes on for a while. Then I get tons of

```
Recovering orphaned file RE1AB6~1.LOG into directory file 534959
```

I have seen a lot of errors relating to the SQL Server reporting services.

What are my options at this point? I would prefer to fix the issue instead of building a new server but I don't know if I can at this point.

Answer (score 1):

No one can really tell you what to do without more information, specifically the SQL Server errors. Personally I'd just copy the SQL log/data files off your RAID, restore from backup, and then restore the current SQL log/data files.

Comment: Agreed.  Copy the data off, it may still be good.  restore from backup.  Anything but continue to use the current file system.

Answer (score 0):

NTFS corruption is serious, and this is almost certainly not related to the failed hard drive (it is possible, but unlikely)

Using windows chkdsk is the next step. Note that it is risky.

My flow would usually be:

- make an image of the system (backup exec system recovery or such)
- --- this may fail due to the disk probs, but you have to try
- stop all sql related services
- chkdsk c: /X   // replace c: with your drive

Hope for the best.

This is not a good situation.

Comment: Regarding imaging failing, most imaging software can take a image of the physical disk or partition rather than just the file system.